# Cross browser issue with window.opener.insertHTML

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser

This code works fine in Firefox **window.opener.insertHTML** but it doesnot work for IE. I just noticed that this code works even for IE9 but its not working for IE8

How can i get it to work for both the browsers?

Comment: window.opener.insertHTML

Comment: If you need write large amount of JS code, you might want to consider libraries like jQuery. It takes away most of the cross-browser problem, so that you can concentrate your effort on application logic.

Comment: Can you add all the code? Like how you open the window? opener should be cross browser, but maybe you open the new window in a way that IE doesn't like.

Comment: @hongster thanks for suggestion but the scope of the project wants me to write javascript

Comment: @hongster - so what jQuery will replace *insertHTML*? If you can find it, perhaps you can extract it and post it as a stand alone function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [insertHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/rich-text_editing_in_mozilla) command is for documents in design mode. It is a Mozilla invention and apparently isn't supported by IE.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with pasteHTML insted of InsertHtml.